How to use the puppeteer to screeshot a website with dynamic and moving content? (node.js )
When trying to navigate to a website using a puppeteer, the full screenshot of static websites is executed perfectly. However, when trying to navigate to a website with dynamic content, such as https://www.schoox.com/, or https://www.cyclopt.com/, the screenshot taken is greatly distorted.
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer')

const config = {
  launchOptions: {
    headless: false,
    args: [
        // Required for Docker version of Puppeteer
        '--no-sandbox',
        '--disable-setuid-sandbox',
        // This will write shared memory files into /tmp instead of /dev/shm,
        // because Docker’s default for /dev/shm is 64MB
        '--disable-dev-shm-usage',
        // load browser extensions
        `--disable-extensions-except=${cookieIgnorePath}`,
        `--load-extension=${cookieIgnorePath}`,
      ]
  },
  viewport: {
    width: 1366, 
    height: 1600
  }
}


function processInputUrl(url) {
  url = url.trim()

  if (!(url.toLowerCase().search('http:') === 0 || url.toLowerCase().search('https:') === 0)) {
    url = "http://".concat(url)
  }

  // ToDO: add protection against XSS

  return url

}

async function getWebpageImage(url, imagePath) {

  return puppeteer.launch(config.launchOptions)
    .then(async browser => {

      let succeeded = true

      try {
        const page = await browser.newPage()

        await page.setViewport(config.viewport)

        await page.goto(url, {"waitUntil": "networkidle0"})

        // auto scroll to the bottom of the page
        await autoScroll(page);
    
        // hide scrollbar 
        await page.evaluate(() => { 
          document.querySelector('html').style.overflow = 'hidden'
        }) 

        // let source = await page.content()

        await page.screenshot({ path: imagePath, fullPage: true})
      }

      catch(err) {
        console.log('Website cannot be reached')
        console.log(err)

        succeeded = false
      }

      await browser.close()

      return succeeded
    })
}


// Function to scroll to the bottom of the page
async function autoScroll(page) {
  await page.evaluate(async () => {
    await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      let totalHeight = 0;
      const distance = 100;
      const maxScrollAttempts = 50;

      const timer = setInterval(() => {
        const scrollHeight = document.body.scrollHeight;
        window.scrollBy(0, distance);
        totalHeight += distance;

        // If scrolled to the bottom of the page or reached max scroll attempts
        if (totalHeight >= scrollHeight || maxScrollAttempts <= 0) {
          clearInterval(timer);
          resolve();
        }
        maxScrollAttempts--;
      }, 100); // scroll speed
    });
  });
}`

The autoscroll function was added later, but the problem remains even if that part is commented out. Lastly, in the package.json, I use "puppeteer": "^2.0.0".
These are executed in docker containers and the ultimate goal is to be able to take a screenshot of all websites. Any suggestions please?

There's no real way to take a screenshot of every website. It's always a best-effort endeavor and there will always be some sites that simply don't behave as expected. Just considering cookie banner overlays makes it impossible to get a clean shot, never mind arbitrary async resource loading. There are no silver bullets in web scraping. networkidle0 will time out on any site that keeps long-running requests open, so that's out of the picture straight up. See the link for details.

@ggorlen thank you for your immediate response. I guess I have to settle for a number of websites. I still have not figured out completely why that is the case, because ideally, the puppeteer web crawler would navigate to the website, scroll down the webpage as far as ordered to and then take a full screenshot. I have a gap of knowledge of how some of these websites work.

It's pretty easy to picture a counterexample. Some sites load a banner or disable scrolling for a bit, like news sites that have a cookie prompt modal or rate limiting block. If the scroll is enabled after some arbitrary time (waiting for a bunch of products or tweets to load, for example), the autoscroll may think it's done and the screenshot is taken before the page is "fully loaded".
